# Rails 4 search function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have this simple search function:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
 def index
    if params[:search].blank?
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @results = Post.search(params[:search])
    end
  end
end
```

I want to implement the following functionalities but I am struggling to code:

1.How to record each of the input search terms and see whether which search terms are the most searched ones. I thought of using "first_or_create" method...

2.Give I have this title: "Peter Paul Mary", how do I split them and link_to each terms to search the search function

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

1.I think you can use two-dimensional array containing results of query for each single term.

```
@maching_posts = Array.new
@terms = params[:search].split

@terms.each do |term|
  result = Post.where(title: term)
  @maching_post << result
end
```

Now, you have array '@maching_post' containing results of query for each single term. Row [0] contains result of first term etc.

You can use this array to generate view. Like this:

```
<% @terms.each_with_index do |term, index| %>
  <span>Results of <%= term %></span>
  <% @maching_post[index].each do |post| %>
    <%= post.title %></br>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

2.To get single words from string you can use split() method.

```
       "Peter Paul Mary".split
```

This method returns array ["Peter", "Paul", "Mary"]
To link each term, use

```
link_to 'term', controller: :search, action: :index, search: 'term'
```

You should use this method in loop, like

```
<% "Peter Paul Mary".split.each do |term| %>
  <%= link_to term, controller: :search, action: :index, search: term %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the link_to part, it works perfectly. But my first question just want to calculate the search terms entered by users, I was not going to sort the posts. E.g. if users search "mary peter", "mary Paul", "peter mary", clearly, mary ranks first and peter ranks second. Should I create a specific model for that? Please advise.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I improved code. You needn't create a new model. Query management is task of controller